# Getting syntax error with Python subproc call

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have this code (someone else's project - I don't really know Python at all).

```
# Get number of pages
cmd = f"pdftk {original} dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{{print $2}}'"
```

and I am getting this error:

> ```
>   File "server.py", line 29
>     cmd = f"pdftk {original} dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{{print $2}}'"
>                                                                                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

anyone know what might be wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Can you please share more code and complete stacktrace (what is the value of `original`) ? Looking at the provided code, looks like it is running a command on unix server.

Comment: Please show us the result of `python3 --version` on the command-line; it may be that your version of Python is not recent enough to use f-strings.

Comment: yeah it was Python version 2, I didn't realize I was using it by mistake